# boost::property_tree C++ JSON Writer, unwanted number formating

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

i am writing JSON files using boost::property_tree, my JSON contains large numbers, numbers are comma separated with **EN_US.UTF-8** locale or separated by space with **fr_FR.UTF-8** locale, i cannot get rid of the locale because i need to properly write utf-8 characters (éàè...).

In my case this behaviour is unwanted... someone has already encountered this problem ?

```
// on top of the main function
locale::global(locale("fr_FR.UTF-8"));
```

Comment: You actually don't need a UTF-8 locale to write UTF-8 characters. They are just a bunch of bytes and you can write bytes perfectly well using any locale.

Comment: Hey, without any locale set, every special characters are in unicode format (ex: \u5741) in the final json file

Comment: I don't quite understand what it means. Files contain bytes. Unicode characters are one possible interpretation of bytes. To understand what characters are there, we need to understand what bytes are there first. So what bytes are there, and how are you writing them? You have a solution so all this is a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED] everything work like a charm with the locale C.UTF-8